# cant display simple text onContentPrepare

Tags: php, joomla-api, joomla-4.x, plugin-events

I just want to display simple text and this is not working.

I don't know is there a way to see something like `log` to see what happens in the background?

```
 public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
        $row->text = str_replace("LOREM", "some thing", $row->text);
        echo "print some thing";
        return "print some thing";
    }
```

I try in three way to display some thing.

Comment: To see what's happening in the background I'd recommend to use a good IDE (PHPStorm, Visual Studio etc) in combination with XDebug. That combination gives you the possibility to step through your code, and see all variables and their values.

Comment: To address one of your attempts: [Joomla Documentation: Plugin/Events/Content](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#:~:text=on%20the%20context.-,Return%20Value,None.,-Results%20are%20returned) and [Creating a content plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_content_plugin#:~:text=plugin%20codes%20here-,//no%20return%20value,-%7D)  Sometimes when I am debugging and want to output to my screen, I use `Factory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage()` ...maybe give that a try, I don't know if it will work, I didn't test it.  [Example](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23572/12352)

Comment: @mickmackusa tnx, that worked too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why `CMSPlugin` does not work for this problem.
the first step is to delete `namespace` on the `.xml` file and then use `JPlugin` instead of  `CMSPlugin`

```
class PlgContentFirstplugin extends JPlugin
{
    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
        $row->text = str_replace("LOREM", "normal Lorem", $row->text);
    }
}
```